# Traefik:v2 Windows Container Failed to retrieve information of the docker client and server host

Tags: windows, docker, traefik

I ran docker image traefik:v2.1.4-windowsservercore-1809 in Windows Server 2019 with 4GB memory (Amazon EC2 t2.medium instance) and got the following error.

$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 -v $PWD/traefikdata:C:/etc/traefik --entrypoint /traefik traefik:v2.1.4-windowsservercore-1809 --configfile=C:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
time="2020-02-15T11:30:12Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from file: C:\etc\traefik\traefik.toml"
time="2020-02-15T11:30:12Z" level=error msg="Failed to retrieve information of the docker client and server host: error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running." providerName=docker
time="2020-02-15T11:30:12Z" level=error msg="Provider connection error error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running., retrying in 552.330144ms" providerName=docker

The traefik.toml is

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
  address = ":80"

[api]
  insecure = true

[providers]  
  [providers.docker]
  endpoint = "npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"
```

The traefik version is

```
Version:      2.1.4
Codename:     cantal
Go version:   go1.13.7
Built:        2020-02-06T17:12:23Z
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

The Docker daemon.json is

```
{   
    "hosts":  [
                  "npipe://"
              ]
}
```

Docker version 19.03.5, build 2ee0c57608

What is wrong with my configuration? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need to map named pipe. The following commnad works fine.
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 -v $PWD/traefikdata:C:/etc/traefik --volume .\pipe\docker_engine:.\pipe\docker_engine --entrypoint /traefik traefik:v2.1.4-windowsservercore-1809
--configfile=C:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml